# How do i create a react-native animation that is similar to reveal effect?

Tags: react-native, animation

I have to animate an svg component that reveals from top to bottom. It will be similar to easing in but the difference is that it should not ease in the component uniformly at the same time. It should start from the top and gradually show the bottom of the component in about 3ms.

How do i do this with react native animations?